# Installer window with multilingual drop dawn using MSI file

Tags: c++, winapi, wix, windows-installer, win32gui

Maybe it's a silly question but I can't find an answer. I want to create minor 1 window EXE installer on WinApi which will have a drop down with possibility to choose language. Then inside on exit from that installer I want to run MSI file with the correct language code as an argument. I figured out how to do it if MSI installer lies in the same directory, but for me it's not the best solution.
I would like to include MSI into the EXE installer bundle through RC file. Is it possible? If so, please describe...

Comment: It's easy just to put -1, wouldn't it be more useful to help???

Comment: As I said below, I didn't downvote - I never do unless an answer is wrong or dangerous - or "[actively unhelpful](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/05/)" as Jon Skeet put it (we all have different approaches - personally I sometimes want to upvote something several times - or give it a higher score - rather than downvote). That being said, I had a hard time trying to understand your question - just a language issue perhaps. Please try to provide a clearer context for us to understand. Step-by-step bullet points often seem to help, and maybe a screen shot or mock-up of some sort?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution. Well described way how it can be done with EXE file can be found [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/TechTwaddle/archive/2009/10/16/how-to-embed-an-exe-inside-another-exe-as-a.aspx).

P.S. For all those "super guru coders" which can only put -1 with no comments - if you don't like question arguments please, else leave the page!!!

Comment: I didn't downvote your question (or answer), but I want to add that your embedded exe might throw off anti-virus and malware detectors and potentially cause you a lot of grief for deployment. **Regardless of how harmless the files are - this sort of embedding is clearly a potential malware vector**. You should check the exe using an online service such as http://www.virustotal.com (60+ virus and malware scanners) to check if it throws off any scanners. If you do trigger any alerts, your deployed exe is likely to be quarantined and you would see endless MSI self-repair trying to put it back.

Comment: Thanks a lot for info)

Comment: I've checked and from 63 antiviruses only 2 (I've never heard about them before) marked my EXE as not safe, all other were good with it.

Comment: Well, that is good news at least. But you never know what is going to happen as you start the "extraction" process of the embedded EXE at runtime. That could be "suspicious behavior". Can I ask why this unusual concept is really needed?

Comment: I'm creating a multilingual EXE installer and inside I embedded MSI installers for each language. I didn't want to use WIX transform method.